# Locator for locating button element does not work when placed in the code but it works in Chrome internal search

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

https://www.dell.com/en-us/cart?cs=19&~ck=mn

If we don't have active cart item then search for "Laptops " in the search bar and then Add one cart item to it .Click on " Go to Cart" now it will land on cart page . Where the checkout button will be Listed under "Cart Summary". I want you to locate that Checkout button. Kindly help me in locating it.

When I tried locating with below Xpath it works in ChromSearch Tab but when I placed in the C# code and try it throws an exception.

```
(//*[text()='Checkout'])[1]
```

or

```
(//button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][text()='Checkout'])[1]
```

Kindly share me the locator to locate the `Checkout` button in cart using C#

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("aside.visible-md.visible-lg button.continueButton"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//aside[@class='visible-md visible-lg col-md-4 clearfix ng-scope']//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block continueButton']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: @KeshavBabu Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.